# Where does Ethereum node store its variant?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

It's known to all that once the smart contract is deployed to the Ethereum network, it won't be modified. But what about the value of a contact's variant? Say a smart contract looks like:

```
...
contract Hello{
      uint256 var1 = 10;
      function changeVar1() public{
             var1 = 100;
      }
}
...
```

So my question is where is the variant var1 stored in Ethereum? **Is it a part bytecode of the smart contract?(I guess it is stored this way)** If so, its value exists in memory of EVM when you run the contract and each time you run the smart contract again the value of var1 is initialized as 10. **If not, where is it stored exactly ?** And can I see the value of var1 changed by the previous transaction which called the function changeVar1()?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum node storage system depends on what node software you are running. It is an implementation detail.

For example, [Parity uses RocksDB](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13639/database-used-for-parity) and you can find these files on your disk when running a Parity node.

Furthermore you can run your node [in the full archive mode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/59662/620) and it stores all historical states on the disk. It is around 2 TB at the moment.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "node software" ?

Comment: Go Ethereum, Parity or similar. Whatever you run to sync with peer-to-peer Ethereum network.

Comment: Well, run the Go Ethereum. So do you have some idea about that ?

Comment: Yes, it stores data on your hard disk using LevelDB (guess, not 100% sure).